# Java code returning null instead of a string

Tags: java, string, return, return-value

I wrote simple code as below. Basically in `setString`, I input "Sentence" as the string and in `getString`, it is supposed to return the string. When I test in Junit, it says that `getString` is returning null instead of "sentence".

```
public class MyString implements MyStringInterface{
    public String str;

    //Sets the value of the current string
    public void setString(String str){
        str = "Sentence";
    }

    // Returns the current string
    public String getString(){
        return str;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use an IDE.

Answer (score 5):

```
public void setString(String str){
    str = "Sentence";
}
```

In your code when you call `str = "Sentence"`  you are actually changing the local varible.

In your `setString` method you are setting the value to the method local variable, not to the instance variable. So your instance variable value will not get changed and it will have it default value which is null.
You can change your method as follows

```
public void setString(String str){
    this.str = "Sentence"; // this.str = str;
}
```

P.S

In your code you are setting a fix value in the setter method. That is a very bad practice, You don't need to have a setter for do a thing like that.

Comment: @javabeginner And keep it in mind that it is not the proper way to use a setter method. If str is going to have a fixed value. There is no point creating a setter method for it. Setter method is meant allow changing the value of instance fields

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `setString()` should be

```
    public void setString(String str){
        this.str = str;
    }
```

And then you need to invoke from your main method

```
MyString s = new MyString();
s.setString("Sentence");
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I had to first create an interface and then developed a class that implements the interface. Then I need to create test cases in Junit to test the program. My question is: where would the main method be? Since I am using Junit, I believe we do not create a main method. In that case, where should I have the code that is used to invoke from the main method?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void setString(String str){
        str = "Sentence";
    }
```

Here "str" in the method body refers to the the string variable "str" that was passed as a parameter to the method. If you have a instance variable with the same name as the parameter name, then use

```
    this.str = str;
```

"this" refers to the self, hence this.str refers the instance variable.  In the above case we are overriding the variable and hence the value is not being set to the instance variable.

Otherwise you can do as follows:

```
    public void setString(String formalParamStr){
        str = formalParamStr;
    }
```

Now call the method as follows:

```
    instanceVar.setString("Sentence");
```